# Pytest fixture with scope "class" running on every method

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to create a test environment with Pytest. The idea is to group test methods into classes.

For every class/group, I want to attach a `config` fixture that is going to be parametrized. So that I can run all the tests with "configuration A" and then all tests with "configuration B" and so on.

But also, I want a `reset` fixture, that can be executed before specific methods or all methods of a class.

**The problem I have there is, once I apply my `reset` fixture (to a method or to a whole class), the `config` fixture seems to work in the function scope instead of the class scope. So, once I apply the `reset` fixture, the `config` fixture is called before/after every method in the class.**

The following piece of code reproduces the problem:

```
import pytest
from pytest import *

@fixture(scope='class')
def config(request):
    print("\nconfiguring with %s" % request.param)
    yield
    print("\ncleaning up config")

@fixture(scope='function')
def reset():
    print("\nreseting")

@mark.parametrize("config", ["config-A", "config-B"], indirect=True)
#@mark.usefixtures("reset")
class TestMoreStuff(object):

    def test_a(self, config):
        pass

    def test_b(self, config):
        pass

    def test_c(self, config):
        pass
```

The test shows how the `config` fixture should work, being executed only once for the whole class. If you uncomment the `usefixtures` decoration, you can notice that the `config` fixture will be executed in every test method. **Is it possible to use the `reset` fixture without triggering this behaviour?**

Comment: This is actually a bug in Pytest 3.2.5: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2938

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, that seems to be a bug in Pytest 3.2.5.

There's a workaround, which is to "force" the scope of a parametrization. So, in this case if you include the `scope="class"` in the `parametrize` decorator, you get the desired behaviour.

```
import pytest
from pytest import *

@fixture(scope='class')
def config(request):
    print("\nconfiguring with %s" % request.param)
    yield
    print("\ncleaning up config")

@fixture(scope='function')
def reset():
    print("\nreseting")

@mark.parametrize("config", ["config-A", "config-B"], indirect=True, scope="class")
@mark.usefixtures("reset")
class TestMoreStuff(object):

    def test_a(self, config):
        pass

    def test_b(self, config):
        pass

    def test_c(self, config):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of pytest you are using.

There are some semantical problems to implement this in older versions of `pytest`. So, this idea is not yet implemented in older `pytest`. Someone has already given suggestion to implement the same. you can refer [this](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1552)

"Fixture scope doesn't work when parametrized tests use parametrized fixtures".
This was the bug.
You can refer [this](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1697)

This issue has been resolved in latest version of pytest. Here's the [commit](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/1766/commits/d72afe7e08033c5e6268ec77f68e894fb1b6bab1) for the same with `pytest 3.2.5`

Hope it would help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm currently using version 3.2.5, and checking the bug you mentioned, I can see it's fixed in my version. But I guess that fix doesn't apply to fixtures being applied to classes.

Comment: Yeah possible.you can try scope `session` if there are no other affected class or tests.

Comment: Version 3.6.2 doesn't seem to behave any different. The solution proposed by @GustavoMeira is still required.